# How sql server compares strings

Tags: sql-server-2012

How sql server compares strings! Can he identify the bigest or the smallest between two  chains
for example
One date in string format: "2019-01-02 00:00:00"
How does she see this string of characters?

Comment: Please format/ rephrase your question properly!

Comment: An understand the tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server uses "Collation" to compare strings. Here's a Microsoft article explaining collation:

- [Collation and Unicode Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017)